# log4net Disable stack trace but preserve exception message

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

How do I configure log4net to render message with exception message but WITHOUT stack trace?

I've tried

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <IgnoresException value="False" />
</layout>
```

but it cuts out all information about the exception and prints out only a custom message. I want to preserve the exception message and get rid of the stack trace.

If there's no way of doing this by configuration only, should I write my own appender from scratch? Or PatternLayout would sufficient?

Comment: do you have conversionpattern element defined inside layout?

Comment: Yes, it looks like this: `<conversionPattern value="%-5p %d{hh:mm:ss} %message%newline"/>`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to just use the message from the exception you can use `%exception{message}` in your `<conversionPattern>` which should still display the exception message even with `<IgnoresException value="False" />`.

e.g.

```
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <IgnoresException value="False" />
    <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d{hh:mm:ss} %message (%exception{message})%newline"/>
</layout>
```

That said, I advise caution with this approach, throwing away the stack trace altogether can cause hours of frustration as it can become much more difficult to track down the source of exceptions.